# Matplotlib conditional marker colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a plot using matplotlib of timestamp vs price and on the same plot, overlay a conditional marker (blue or red) if the value in column 'B/S' is either B or S. No marker if the value is 'NaN'. Plotting the time and price is simple enough but I can't seem to figure out how to do place those conditional markers. I've already tried looking for solutions on this site and others but haven't found one that is a close approximation of this.

```
df = 
            timestamp         price   B/S
0       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 1     NaN
1       2018-04-24 06:02:02.600 1     NaN
2       2018-04-24 06:03:02.600 2     NaN
3       2018-04-24 06:04:02.600 4     B
4       2018-04-24 06:05:02.775 2     NaN
5       2018-04-24 06:06:02.825 3     NaN
6       2018-04-24 06:07:03.050 5     NaN
7       2018-04-24 06:08:03.125 6     S
8       2018-04-24 06:09:03.275 7     NaN
9       2018-04-24 06:10:03.300 4     NaN
10      2018-04-24 06:11:03.300 3     NaN
11      2018-04-24 06:12:03.950 5     B
12      2018-04-24 06:15:04.050 5     NaN
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can do it as a oneliner. But the following code should do the trick.

```
markers = {"B": {"marker": "o", "color": "b"}, "S": {"marker": "v", "color": "r"}}
for marker in markers:
    plt.scatter(df[df['B/S'] == marker].timestamp,
                df[df['B/S'] == marker].price,
                marker=markers[marker]['marker'],
                color=markers[marker]['color'])
```

Depending on the complexity of the data in B/S. If there are hundreds of different values then maybe you need some generator for the marker+color combination. But I guess that there only are two values based on the header.

Comment: Hi JMDE, thanks for your response. I tried this approach but get an error:


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-22ca92db4c55> in <module>()
     57                finalDF[finalDF['B/S'] == marker].EntryPrice,
     58                marker = markers[marker]['marker'],
---> 59                color = markers[marker]['color'])
     60 
     61


TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: Late answer. You have probably moved on. But probably it is due to that you send in the Pandas.Series and not the values. Try `finalDF[finalDF['B/S'] == marker].EntryPrice.values`